# PHP file upload not working - tried lots of tutorial websites, permissions correct, php.ini correct

Tags: php, upload

I am hosting a file upload script on an digital ocean server. I have copied line for line tutorials from all over the internet and changed my permissions using CHMOD 777. I cannot for the life of me figure out why the file won't upload.

PHP

```
<?php
$target_path = "uploads/";

$target_path = $target_path . basename( $_FILES['uploadedfile']['name']); 

if(move_uploaded_file($_FILES['uploadedfile']['tmp_name'], $target_path)) {
    echo "The file ".  basename( $_FILES['uploadedfile']['name']). 
    " has been uploaded";
} else{
    echo "There was an error uploading the file, please try again!";
}
?>
```

HTML

```
<form enctype="multipart/form-data" action="upload_manager.php" method="POST">
<input type="hidden" name="MAX_FILE_SIZE" value="100000" />
Choose a file to upload: <input name="uploadedfile" type="file" /><br />
<input type="submit" value="Upload File" />
</form>
```

The file I'm trying to upload is only a few hundred KB and is a PNG. I have tried JPEG too.

When I print out the value of

```
$_FILES['uploadedfile']['tmp_name']
```

It is empty

The value of

```
$_FILES['uploadedfile']['name']
```

is the file name.

I had a look at my php ini and everything related to uploading files is correct.

What else can I try to get this to work?

Comment: Did you do a `var_dump($_FILES)` to see the value of `$_FILES["uploadedfile"]["error"]`?

Comment: What is the size of file you uploaded????

Comment: array(1) { ["uploadedfile"]=> array(5) { ["name"]=> string(7) "pic.png" ["type"]=> string(0) "" ["tmp_name"]=> string(0) "" ["error"]=> int(2) ["size"]=> int(0) } }

Comment: check `upload_max_filesize` in `php.ini` file

Comment: hard to say whether your upload to folder code is correct (that isn't in your question). If you're running this on a local machine, make sure that temp folder exists and isn't full and permissions to write to it. seems to be the issue here

Comment: The upload folder is located in the same dir as the php file and html file. It has all the permissions. chmod 777 and /tmp/ has chmod 777 on it too. So I don't see how permissions are the issue.

Comment: have a look at the php documentation for [error codes](http://php.net/manual/en/features.file-upload.errors.php) your file is to big. You can change the php.ini settings. Are you using apache or nginx?

Comment: `error_reporting(E_ALL); `use this at top of php file  // Report all errors

Comment: Weird, I'm using apache and in the php.ini the max upload size is; Maximum allowed size for uploaded files.
; http://php.net/upload-max-filesize
upload_max_filesize = 2M

Comment: Check the size of image you uploaded!!

Comment: can you print the value of $target_path

Comment: I have checked the size Saty, it is 176KB. That is definitely smaller than 2Mb.

Comment: Chandu it outputs "uploads/pic.png"

Comment: Prashant Tapase, I have that there, it isn't outputting anything.

Comment: Ok I increased the file limit on php.ini to 10M and everything works now. I don't understand why it was failing on files larger than 120k when the limit was 2M. What's up with that?